# How Active Record validation check, if type is array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have attribute user`s languages. When form submit, it must return array?

I want to write validation in model User:

`validates :languages, presence: true`

How write in validates, returning value must be is array?

Comment: Are you saving this field? How is languages defined in the database?

Comment: in migration `add_column :users, :languages, :string, array: true, default: []`, 
strong parameters: `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, languages: [])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class User< ApplicationRecord
  validate :languages_is_array

  def languages_is_array
    if !languages.kind_of?(Array)
      errors.add(:languages, "must be an array")
    end
  end

  #Another version, as moveson commented
  def languages_is_array
    errors.add(:languages, "must be an array") unless languages.kind_of?(Array)
  end

end
```

Comment: Ruby idiom is to use `unless` instead of `if` followed by `!`. So in this case, `unless languages.kind_of?(Array)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare that a param needs to be an array in you controller if you are concerned about what the user submits in the form and not so much the validation of the model.

See: [Action Controller Overview - 4.5 Strong Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values, map the key to an empty array:
>
> ```
> params.permit(id: [])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own custom validator for attributes.

In this case it could look like:

```
class ArrayValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value.is_a? Array
      record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || "must be an array")
    end
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :languages, array: true
end
```

See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators